# Matlab tabling syntax

Tags: matlab, printf, format-string

New to matlab and I cannot understand a bit of code I have been given:

```
x = 1; % initial guess = 1 
Tol = 5e-9; % correct to 8 decimal places 
count = 0; 
f=0.54030231; % f(1)= 0.54030231 
fprintf('step x f(x)\n') 
fprintf('---- ----------- ----------\n') 
fprintf('%1i %12.8f %12.8f\n',count,x,f) 
while abs(f)>Tol %loop until the absolute value of f is smaller than tolerance
count = count + 1 
deriv = -sin(x); ; % first derivative of f(x) 
x2 = x - (f/deriv); % new value of x 
x = x2; 
f = cos (x); % new value of f(x) 
fprintf('%3i %12.8f %12.8f\n',count,x,f) 
end
```

The program is newtons method for finding roots of equations which I understand.

What I don't understand is this part:

```
fprintf('---- ----------- ----------\n') 
fprintf('%1i %12.8f %12.8f\n',count,x,f)
```

Questions:

1. Why is the last bit of the second line divided by n?
2. What are the numbers in the second line i.e. %1i, %12.8f etc?
3. How does this work with the 'count, x, f' that is written after it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html)? If you didn't, why not? If you did, what is it that you don't understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\n is a newline character.

For the rest, you're looking at Matab's version of printf [format strings](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html).  With slight variations these are used in dozens of languages. Count, x, and f are inserted at the `%` `1i` is a integer with 1 digit, `12.8f` is a floating point number with 12 characters, 8 after the decimal.